# Prime field of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I'm stuck in the last step of a proof of this theorem:

> If $K$ is a field, then its prime field is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$
>   or to $\mathbb{F}_p$ for some $p$.

In particular I'm following the one in Rotman's book "Advanced Modern Algebra" (pp. XXX).

Suppose the image of the homomorphism $\chi: \mathbb{Z} \to K$ defined by $\chi(n)=n$ is isomorphic $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

In this case, we want to prove that $\mathrm{im} \,\chi=
\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{F}_p$ is also the prime field of $K$. The proof in the book reads:

> Clearly $\mathrm{im} \,\chi$ is the prime field of $k$, for every
>   subfield constains $\epsilon$, hence contains $\mathrm{im} \,\chi$.

That sentence shows that $\mathrm{im} \,\chi$ belongs to the prime field of $K$, but I have trouble seeing the other direction. **Why is the prime field contained in $\mathrm{im} \,\chi$?**

I'm sure it is quite obvious, but I don't get it. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What is your definition of a prime field? The prime field should be the "smallest field contained in K". So it is to note, that any field contained in K also containes $\mathbb F _p$.

Comment: The smallest subring is the ring generated by $1$ which is $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ (in that case $n=p$ is prime for the ring having no zeros divisors). The prime field is the field generated by $1$ (the smallest subfield) ie. $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{F}_p$

Answer (score 2):

Let the multiplicative and additive identities of $K$ be $1_K$ and $0_K.$ Let $f(0)=0_K$ and $f(n)=1_K+f(n-1)$ for $n\in \mathbb N.$ Any sub-field $F\subset K$ contains $0_K$ and $1_K$, and, since $F$ is closed under addition, $F\supset \{0_k\}\cup \{f(n): n\in \mathbb N\}.$

If there exists $n\in \mathbb N$ with $f(n)=0_K$ then the least such $n$ must be a prime number $p.$ In this case $F_p=\{f(n):0\leq n\leq p-1\}$ is a field and we conclude that any sub-field $F\subset K$  has $F_p$ as a sub-field of $F.$ So $F_p$ is the unique minimal sub-field of $K.$

If $f(n)\ne 0_K$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$ then any sub-field $F\subset K$ must contain, as a  subset, the sub-field $G =\{0\}\cup \{\pm f(m)/f(n): m,n\in \mathbb N\}.$ In this case  $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q$ and any sub-field $F \subset K$ has $G$ as a sub-field of $F.$ So $G$ is the unique minimal sub-field of $K. $